# MySQL, Permission Issue

Tags: mysql, permissions, navicat

I have a MySQL database that has several databases used by more than 1 web app.

I need to now create a new Database that can only be accessed via a new user account. I've been using Navicat v5.3.3 manage users to try to set this up but it doesn't seem to work and I don't know if that's bec of MySQL or Navicat.

But given that I want a new DB that a new account can only access (not the other dbs) what's the best way to set this up?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to create your database and grant to the user the desired privileges, you should start a mysql query tool and type following queries:

```
CREATE DATABASE foobar;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON foobar.* TO 'foobar_user'@'localhost'
IDENTIFIED BY 'goodsecret';
```

you can take a look at the MySQL manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'd usually use phpMyAdmin or the MySQL command-line interface.
Create the database and (using your superuser account), make sure the user has appropriate permissions on that database.

Something like:

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name;
GRANT ALL ON database_name.* TO new_user@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

That will give 'new_user' all privileges over the contents of database_name, provided that user is connected from localhost using 'password'.

If you want a GUI though - I highly recommend phpMyAdmin (http://www.phpmyadmin.net/)

EDIT: Based on your description, you'll also want to make sure the permissions on the other databases are set to prevent this new user accessing them; you can use 'SHOW GRANTS' to see which users have privileges over which tables - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug